# How to set specific return type to scope if possible?

Tags: rust

I have this scope in the print macro that tries to find an integer between 1 and 1 billion. If it fails, it should panic.

```rust
fn main() {
    println!(
        "{}",
        {
            for i in 0..1000000000 {
                if i == 100 {
                    Some(i)
                }
            }
            None
        }
        .unwrap()
    );
}
```

At the line with `Some(i)` it has an error:

```
mismatched types
expected unit type `()`
        found enum `Option<{integer}>`
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I realize this is probably a toy example, but if your real code has the `for`-`if`-`Some`-`None` pattern, then it could be expressed as iterator methods: `(0..1000000000).find(|i| *i == 100).unwrap()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use if as an expression you have to provide an else as well.
I think you want something else though, break out of that block early.
You can do that with the recently stabilized named blocks:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!(
        "{}",
        'bl: {
            for i in 0..1000000000 {
                if i == 100 {
                    break 'bl Some(i);
                }
            }
            None
        }
        .unwrap()
    );
}
```